# query in c function with | operator in the argument

Tags: c

Can someone explain me what exactly is the following function doing? This is the first time I have come across a function call with | operator.

```
    static inline int ieee80211_is_data_qos(__le16 fc)
    {
    /*
     * mask with QOS_DATA rather than IEEE80211_FCTL_STYPE as we just need
     * to check the one bit
     */
    return (fc & htole16(IEEE80211_FCTL_FTYPE | IEEE80211_STYPE_QOS_DATA)) ==
           htole16(IEEE80211_FTYPE_DATA | IEEE80211_STYPE_QOS_DATA);
    }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: Have you considered reading a C tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a function call, it's a `return` statement. Putting the argument of `return` inside parentheses to make it look like a function call is a ... style choice made by some C programmers. I find it highly dubious and consider it a severe smell, myself.

Anyway, the function simply does a computation and the resulting value is returned. The bitwise or operator (`|`) is used to compute the argument for the function `htole16()`, whose return value is then bitwise-and:ed (`&`)  with the argument and compared to the return value of a second call to the same function.

In modern C, the return type should be `bool` since that's way clearer (the result of `==` is what is being returned here).

You'd use it like so:

```
const int x = ieee80211_is_data_qos(myFc);
```

where `myFc` should be a value of type `__le16`.

Comment: There is a reason why no one shouldn't treat `return` as a Function in `c`. :D

Answer (score 0):

It is performing bitwise OR `|` between `IEEE80211_FCTL_FTYPE` and `IEEE80211_STYPE_QOS_DATA`. And then sending the result to the function `htole16()`.

Later the result of `htole16()` is bitwise and:ed with `fc`.

---

Just like calling a function `foo(a + b);`, the expression`(a + b)` will be evaluated first and then the result will be sent to the function `foo();`